# Parse retention analytics download or save?

Tags: parse-platform, analytics, retention

I just discovered Parse.com's retention analytics and absolutely love it! It's exactly what every app needs. However, I don't see any way to change the cohort dates (install) or save the results.

Do I need to screen shot this chart every day manually to save the history?  I want to run a variety of competing campaigns and would like to compare the results.

Comment: Anyone from Parse have an answer?